# Redirect PHP-Shell-Script output

Tags: php, bash, redirect, scripting

i have got a php-script foo.php

```
#!/usr/bin/php -c /etc/php5/cli/php.ini -q
<?php
  echo 'hello'; // & do some stuff
?>
```

I call this script **not** wrapped by a sh-script but using it directly in a cron job.
To get rid of it's output i normally would just create a sh-file which calls

```
/usr/bin/php -c /etc/php5/cli/php.ini -q foo.php > /dev/null 2 > /dev/null
```

now i'd like to do this in the interpreter-declaration of the php file it self...
so i am looking for the syntax for:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -args [file's content] > /redirect 2 > /redirect
```

i have kind of a hard time googleing for it... so if anybody could point me into the right direction i would really appreciate it!

Thx in advance

Corelgott

Comment: I think you can redirect the output to /dev/null directly in the cron job commmand (/path/to/script.php > /dev/null) without the need for the sh wrapper.

Comment: ah i see, that was a solution i didn't think about yet. Thanks for pointing it out! The would solve the problem. But i would like to know if my suggested syntax somehow exists...

Comment: You need to remove the space between the "2" and the ">" or if you're redirecting stdout and stderr to the same place: `foo > /dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score 0):

The shebang statement was never intended to control the output of the script, it's more of a *use this program to execute what's underneath here* type deal, as such there's no option for what you want.

Unless the interpreter itself has an output argument (which the php cli doesn't), you will need to keep the `> /dev/null` statement in the crontab line.

You could also modify your scripts to have a global boolean `$output`, surrounding all `print` statements with `if` statements and include that at the top of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Like, @Victor Stanciu said, you redirect the output directly in the cron job command, but the only other way I can think of is:

```
php -r "ob_start(); include 'my_script'; ob_end_clean();"
```

I think you could close stdout with `fclose(STDOUT)`, but apparently the constants `STDIN`, `STDOUT` and `STDERR` no longer exist.